# OpenWhisk Restart Issue

Tags: docker, nginx, openwhisk

Openwhisk and nginx docker

I have successfully deployed openwhisk and all are working fine but after server restart nginx docker is continuously restarting . while checking the dockers logs getting the following error.

root@openwhisk:~# docker logs  fdaa4a93b80e
2018/04/16 13:10:45 [emerg] 1#1: open() "/etc/nginx/nginx.conf" failed (2: No such file or directory)
nginx: [emerg] open() "/etc/nginx/nginx.conf" failed (2: No such file or directory)
2018/04/16 13:10:46 [emerg] 1#1: open() "/etc/nginx/nginx.conf" failed (2: No such file or directory)
nginx: [emerg] open() "/etc/nginx/nginx.conf" failed (2: No such file or directory)
2018/04/16 13:10:46 [emerg] 1#1: open() "/etc/nginx/nginx.conf" failed (2: No such file or directory)
nginx: [emerg] open() "/etc/nginx/nginx.conf" failed (2: No such file or directory)

Anys Clue to fix the issue ??

Comment: You should file an issue https://github.com/apache/incubator-openwhisk/issues as this might be a bug/configuration issue.

Answer (score 0):

When you restart OpenWhisk in the vagrant vm (that is meant for development) you may need to refresh the deployment, as documented here:

https://github.com/apache/incubator-openwhisk/blob/master/tools/vagrant/README.md#safe-re-deploy-after-vm-restart

Some time ago I traced the problem back to the fact configuration files are written in /tmp and removed when you restart the VM. I provided a patch for this but looks like it was lost in translation, so the problem is still there: with Vagrant you should NOT halt the vm, just freeze it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using an old version of OpenWhisk with an old version of Vagrant scripts that was using /tmp/ to store the nginx config files, so on reboot the nginx was not able to mount from /tmp tmpfs because was not ready.
This problem was fixed here: https://github.com/apache/incubator-openwhisk/commit/e325be7e9dcc2fbd5e6d77deb83d8b78328100e0#diff-b84d6a391031d6181fa26b3e4ae9d267

Now all the logs and nginx config file are located in

> ${HOME}/.openwhisk/ansible/tmp

This and many other problems were recently fixed for default Vagrant deployment, please try again

```
# Clone openwhisk
git clone --depth=1 https://github.com/apache/incubator-openwhisk.git 
openwhisk

# Change directory to tools/vagrant
cd openwhisk/tools/vagrant

# Run script to create vm and run hello action
./hello
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the openwhisk nginx restart issue,  created new directory /tmp1 for nginx conf instead of default /tmp directory (which reset while server reboot) in the docker configuration file **openwhisk/ansible/environments/local/group_vars/all**

openwhisk_tmp_dir: "{{ lookup('env', 'OPENWHISK_TMP_DIR')|default('/tmp1', true) }}"